# Как выполнить PHP скрипт через ajax?

Tags: php, java, mysql, ajax

Как выполнить PHP скрипт с помощью ajax?

```
# Если кнопка "Yes" нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['btn_yes'] ))
    {
    // выполняем операции с базой данных
    $mysqli_query ="UPDATE check_vacancy SET control = '1' WHERE id = ".$_POST['rowid'].";";
    $qr_result = mysqli_query($link, $mysqli_query)
    or die(mysqli_error());
    }

    # Если кнопка "No" нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['btn_no'] ))
    {
    // выполняем операции с базой данных
    $mysqli_query ="UPDATE check_vacancy SET control = '0' WHERE id = ".$_POST['rowid'].";";
    $qr_result = mysqli_query($link, $mysqli_query)
    or die(mysqli_error());
    }
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне применить ajax именно в моем случае

Comment: Нужно положить этот скрипт в какой-нибудь файл на сервере (например, `skript.php`) - и вызвать его с помощью ajax через обращение на http://имя.сайта.рф/skript.php